# rpm package installed successfully but does not run

Tags: fedora, i3, bluejeans

setup: i3wm, fedora 31

I am facing this issue, in which some rpm's even after being installed,
For e.g. I have Bluejeans installed, but when I try running the app, it results in command not found, the baffling part being I have no such issue opening it in gnome.

```
  $  rpm -qa | grep -i bluejeans
bluejeans-v2-2.0.0-188.x86_64


$ bluejeans
zsh: bluejeans: command not found...
```

same goes when I try accessing using dmenu.

Comment: What does `rpm -ql bluejeans` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the issue, bluejeans was **not getting installed in /usr/bin** or any other similar paths.

```
rpm -ql bluejeans 
package bluejeans is not installed
```

while they also named package as bluejeans-v2 which made it harder to search, while in gnome I could start using `bluejeans` even from the terminal.

**solution:** 
**create a symlink to /usr/bin** where you have bluejean-v2 installed

```
ls -s /usr/bin/bluejean-v2 ${install_path}/bluejeans-v2
```